# Output not redirected to a file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to list all the files starting with 'e' in `/` using `os.walk()`. But the code seems not to redirect the output to a file rather it displays on the IDE.

```
import os, sys

out = sys.stdout
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     sys.stdout = outfile
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
         for file in files:
             if file.startswith('e'):
                 print file
     sys.stdout = out
```

Could anyone please suggests whats wrong in this code. **And also a if possible a better way to accomplish the above task.**

Comment: I ran your code from ipython notebook and it wrote 7000 filenames starting with 'e' to 'output.txt'.

Comment: Is it NOT at all displaying the output on IDE? I am using PyCharm by the way.

Comment: I just ran it on PyCharm 4.0.6 community, python 2.7.6 (Linux Mint 17) and also had it write all to file.  What version of python are you using?

Comment: I have Python 2.7 too.

Comment: The language reference for the `print` statement explicitly indicates that "Standard output is defined as the file object named `stdout` in the built-in module `sys`."  In fact this is true for all versions of the Python 2 documentation.  So if this doesn't work for you it's technically a bug in your interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python 2:

```
import os

path = r"/"
outfile = 'output.txt'

with open(outfile, 'w') as fh:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('e'):
                print >> fh, file
```

See the documentation for an explanation on print: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

and for Python 3:

```
import os

path = r"/"
outfile = 'output.txt'

with open(outfile, 'w') as fh:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('e'):
                print(fh, file=outfile)
```

Comment: This doesn't have much explanatory value; also the OP is using Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

<del>In your example code, changing the value of `sys.stdout` will not affect the `print` statement, because `print` does not directly use `sys.stdout`.</del> **Edit:** Actually, this worked in my Python interpreter.  But it's the wrong way to do it regardless.

To print to a file, you should specify the file in the `print` statement or function call.  In Python 2, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) is a statement, and you can specify a file like so:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    print >> outfile, "Hello, world!"
```

In Python 3, [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) is a function with an optional `file` argument:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    print("Hello, world!", file=outfile)
```

Alternatively, you can use the methods of the open file object, such as `write()`:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("Hello, world!\n")
```